# Change VB6 Const occurences to use a Function instead

Tags: function, vb6, constants

I am working on an old VB6 project. There, I have a Const

```
Private Const INI_PATH = "C:\MyPath\MyINI.INI"
```

Now the `INI_PATH` has changed from being always set to "C:\MyPath\MyINI.INI", instead now can either be in another directory or at the original location.

I have a function which can be used to get the INI path now according to some conditions.

```
Public Function GetINIPath() As String
```

I was wondering if there is anyway I would be able to do something like

```
INI_PATH = GetINIPath()
```

So, everywhere the INI_PATH was being used, now uses the new path based on the function.

I see that there is no `#define` or similar in VB6.
Do I have any other alternative other than changing all instances of `INI_PATH` into the function `GetINIPath()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, there is no concept of alias or #define in VB6.

But if you don't mind causing a bit of potential confusion for the maintainer, you could do:

```
Private Function INI_PATH() As String
    INI_PATH = <whatever>
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

In VB you do not need parens when calling a function with no arguments, so just create a function called `INI_PATH` and your code will still work.